# which is the best way to implement display username(from user table) and avatar(from the profile table) in all view pages [ASP.NET core]?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, dry

I have a partial view _TopBar with used to display username, avatar. _TopBar is rendered when the user logged.

How to avoid repeating the same code in my MVC project?

Comment: Take a look here: [MVC Layout](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/core/mvc/views/layout?view=aspnetcore-5.0)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a `.cshtml` in `Shared` folder.

In my test project, I create `_LoginPartial.cshtml`.

[image]

**`_LoginPartial.cshtml`.**

[image]

**Add it in `_Layout.cshtml`.**

[image]